# Yii2 select dropdown text

Tags: yii2

If I have a table in mysql like this :

```
mysql> select * from tipe_karyawan;
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | nama_tipe | level |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Stylist   |     1 |
|  2 | Stylist   |     2 |
|  3 | Stylist   |     3 |
|  4 | Therapist |     0 |
+----+-----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I want to display nama_tipe & level, so, I created like this :

```
 <?=
$form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(TipeKaryawan::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama_tipe'.'level'), ['prompt' => 'Select tipe']
)
?>
```

Yii2 said unknown property TipeKaryawan::nama_tipelevel
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php 
  $result=ArrayHelper::map(TipeKaryawan::find()->all(), 'id',
  function($model, $defaultValue) {
      return $model['nama_tipe'].'-'.$model['level'];
  }
  );
?>

<?=  $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList($result  , ['prompt' => 'Select tipe']); ?>
```

Refer : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map%28%29-detail

Comment: Thanks, it works, but in wbraganca dynamic form little weird, the spinner still loaded

Answer (score 0):

I think you should perform the concatenation in select and use alias

```
<?=
    $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(TipeKaryawan::find()->
                    select(' id, concat(nama_tipe, level) as description ')->all(), 
                      'id', 'description'), ['prompt' => 'Select tipe']
    )
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create required array in controller, and then send it to view. Yii2 is MVC.

In controller:

```
$tipes = <Your concatenated array...>;

return $this->render('model' => $model, 'tipes' => $ties);
```

In view:

```
*/*@var $ties array*/
 <?= $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList($ties, ['prompt' => 'Select tipe'])?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **Model** add the next function:

```
public function getConcatenate() {
   return this->nama_type . ' ' . $this->level;
}
```

To get this field, do the following:

Again in your model add:

```
public static function getList() {
 $cat = TipeKaryawan::find()->all();
 return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($cat, 'id', 'concatenate');
}
```

In your **View**

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList( TipeKaryawan::getList() ,   ['prompt' => 'Select tipe']); ?>
```